# Web3 library to use with Laravel

Tags: web3js, php, ethers.js, web3.php

Is there some library like web3.js or ethers.js but in PHP to use with Laravel? 
(Which code is hopefully maintained)
Or is PHP just the strongest choice possible I want to work with web3?

Comment: @Masoudjt Kind of, I was just hoping that there is some more recent and active library.

Comment: Unfortunately they haven't done anything officially about php laravel yet. You can check it in [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/web3php/) also check the github page in that link.